# Finding Confidence Interval using python

Tags: python, statistics, confidence-interval

I am trying to calculate confidence interval using margin of error but it is giving me an error. Below is the code I've written. Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

sample_size=2000
z_critical = stats.norm.ppf(q = 0.95)  

# path        [File location variable]
#Code starts here
data = pd.read_csv(path)
data_sample = data.sample(n=2000, random_state=0)
sample_mean = data_sample['installment'].mean
sample_std = data_sample['installment'].std()
a = sample_size ** 0.5
margin_of_error = z_critical * (sample_std/44.721)
confidence_interval = (sample_mean + margin_of_error, sample_mean - margin_of_error)
```

which gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3f5eda42a1b0> in <module>()
     24 # print(type(a))
     25 margin_of_error = z_critical * (sample_std/a)
---> 26 confidence_interval = (sample_mean + margin_of_error, sample_mean - margin_of_error)
     27 true_mean = data['installment'].mean
     28 print(confidence_interval)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'float'
```

Comment: `sample_mean = data_sample['installment'].mean` is missing `()` at the end

Comment: @DavidBuck ... oops! just posted it as an answer...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60932748/edit) your post with extra information. Don't add it as a comment.

Comment: @DavidBuck Thank you. It worked! Will you please help with correct syntax to define confidence interval range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, this is due to a typo - you are missing parentheses in

```
sample_mean = data_sample['installment'].mean
```

it should be

```
sample_mean = data_sample['installment'].mean()
```

`mean` (no parentheses) is a method and not a float, hence the error when trying to add it to `margin_of_error` (which is indeed a float).